# Twitter Bootstrap 3 breakpoints based on actual width of container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 (and Angular) for a webapp. I have sidebars which can be toggled, they are not using bootstrap (but table-cell layout)

I created a demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0pGjRqfqF21lGvhuNb9k?p=preview

**Is it possible to make bootstrap columns break relative to the actual with of the container they are in?**

Example:
A col-sm-* should break if its container (aside-main) is <768px, not the screen ?

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
<div class="aside-container">
  <div class="aside-main">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h2>Main Content Area</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <strong>column 1</strong>             
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <strong>column 2</strong>             
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aside" ng-if="asideIn">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h2>Aside Area</h2>
      here is the aside content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, breakpoints are relative to things that can be controlled via media queries, which relate to the device, not elements on the page.

Comment: So I think about extending bootstrap with css classes which act like a media query and then duplicating the code in the media query to the new classes... any better solution?

Comment: Well, that's somewhere between very hard and impossible. You're looking for the capability that some people call "element queries", which don't exist and probably never will.

Answer (score 1):

In 2018 seems there are such possibilities.

According to the documentation of project https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries all you have to do is following.

Let's say you have following html element.

```
<div class="parent">
    <h2>Test</h2>
</div>
```

And you define following css

```
.parent h2 {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.parent[min-width~="400px"] h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.parent[min-width~="600px"] h2 {
    padding: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.parent[min-width~="700px"] h2 {
    font-size: 34px;
    color: red;
}
```

And include scripts

```
<script src="src/ResizeSensor.js"></script>
<script src="src/ElementQueries.js"></script>
```

Functionality of the project will find html elements that css is referring to and will only listen to changes of those elements.

> "no performance issues since it listens only on size changes of
>   elements that have element query rules defined through css. "

e.g. when an element that is "watched" exceeds width of 400 on watched element will be added css attribute min-width 400px and defined css will be applied to it.

Also for this to work you need to trigger the event listening or initialization yourself:

```
var ElementQueries = require('css-element-queries/src/ElementQueries');

 //attaches to DOMLoadContent
ElementQueries.listen();

//or if you want to trigger it yourself.
// Parse all available CSS and attach ResizeSensor to those elements which have rules attached
// (make sure this is called after 'load' event, because CSS files are not ready when domReady is fired.
ElementQueries.init();
```

It's not exactly breaking bootstrap columns, but you can control css based on the width of the container. Should suffice.